# usb-c and thunderbolt 3 monitors?

Tags: thunderbolt, 4k-resolution, usb-c

I have a macbook air with mini display port and newer macbook pro with usb-c thunderbolt port. I am looking to get a duel monitor setup that would work with both my laptops. I also want to daisy chain them to save on wires everywhere. They should also be 4k. Im trying to stay in 27 inch size and not looking for curved or ultra-wide unless i haver to.

Does such a monitor even exist? all i find are those that lack the in/out ports. what am i missing? please help if you know such a monitor, list the model number.

Comment: If your Air is old enough to have miniDP it can't even support one 4k screen, let alone two. The other is dependant on spec, which you haven't told us. Either way, specific hardware requests are off-topic.

Comment: Your wrong, it can support two external display up to 4K each. Check the spec sheet.

Comment: You haven't told us which it is.

Comment: mid 2012mac air

Comment: So, two external displays up to 2560x1600 daisy chained via Thunderbolt, not DP. No 4k support at all. Ref: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.7-11-mid-2012-specs.html

Comment: what part of your link are you referring to exactly ?